# Cannot set a proper alignment for a banner on Facebook Canvas (web player game)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas

I am trying to inject a banner inside a Facebook Canvas page, where my game is being displayed. There is a part of my code that is meant to place the banner in the center of the screen, right below an iFrame that contains the game. The banner, as an HTML `<img>` element, is placed inside a `<div>` element:

```js
"banner.setAttribute(\"src\",\"https://www.toyboxgms.com/cloverclash/TwitchyBanner.png\");" +
"banner.setAttribute(\"align\",\"center\");" +
"banner.setAttribute(\"Id\",\"banner\");" 
...
```

If I run the game outside the Facebook Canvas (Mozilla browser), everything is in its place. However, once I play it on Facebook, the banner gets stuck to the left side of the screen like in the [screenshot](http://toyboxgms.com/cloverclash/StackOverflow.png), even though the alignment is clearly set to "`center`". I know that Facebook is only placing my game inside an iFrame and nothing else.

In my case, the banner can only be aligned right or left.  Is there a simple way to change this and centrally align it?